# pass json array as bundle to fragment using android volley

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I want to make a viewpager which takes the data from android volley. i have parsed json as as shown below.

```
    HashMap<String, String> event = new HashMap<String, String>();

        JSONArray timings = object1.getJSONArray("periods");


        for (int t=0; t<timings.length(); t++){
            JSONObject timeObject = timings.getJSONObject(t);

            String period = timeObject.getString("periodName");
            periodList.put("",period);

            System.out.println(period);

            event.put(TAG_PERIOD,period);

        }
```

Now i want to send classroom periods wrt the paticular day(mon,tue, etc.) as below:

[resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cead.png)

i want to send the parsed array to the fragment.
following are the codes for pageradapter and fragment class.

pageradapter:

```
    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;
TabFragment1 fragA, fragB,fragC,fragD,fragE,fragF;


public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

public void setFragments(Context c){

    // Set up the simple base fragments
    fragA = new TabFragment1();
    fragB = new TabFragment1();
    fragC = new TabFragment1();
    fragD = new TabFragment1();
    fragE = new TabFragment1();
    fragF = new TabFragment1();

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = fragA;
            return fragment;

        case 1:
            fragment = fragB;
            return fragment;

        case 2:
            fragment = fragC;
            return fragment;

        case 3:
            fragment = fragD;
            return fragment;

        case 4:
            fragment = fragE;
            return fragment;

        case 5:
            fragment = fragF;
            return fragment;

        default:
            return null;
    }


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

}

Fragment:

```
    public class TabFragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);


}



}
```

I am new to android and watn to know how to pass the parsed data to fragment.

Comment: In which class are you receiving the data from volley?

Comment: data is received in main class

Answer (score 4):

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("response",jsonarray.toString());    
ListFrag newFragment = new ListFrag ();
newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

and in Fragment get the values of bundles,

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
String s = b.getString("response");
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this method for JSON Parsing:**

```
public static <T> T JsonParse(T t, String response)
            throws JsonSyntaxException, IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
        JsonReader reader;
        reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        t = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, t.getClass());
        reader.close();
        return t;
    }
```

Create  two model class:

```
1.public class Model_main{
  public Arraylist<Model_period> mPeriodList=new ArrayList<Model_period>();

}

2.public class Model_period{
   @SerializedName("periodName")
   public String periodName;
}
```

you can directly pass jsonresponse string in budle.and then parsing that response in speicific viewpager.

**Json Parsing using Above method and above model class**

that **response** is getting from volly.

```
Model_Main model_main = JsonParse(new Model_Main(), response);


Arraylist<Model_period>  mList = model_main.mPeriodList;
```

its very simple and helpful.

Please add gson library from dependency in android studio project or add Gson.rar in Lib folder in eclipse.